# admin approves user account php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am doing an admin page for the administrator to approve an account. But once I approve one pending account the rest of the pending accounts will be approved simultaneously.  What I want to happen is if once I approve one pending account the rest of the pending account will remain pending til it's approved. I've been looking for answers and I can't find one. Hopefully you can help me out.

here's the code:

```
      public function approve_user()
       {     $id= $this->session->userdata('uid');
           $rajan =$this->user_model->update_user(array('user_ID',$id));
      /*$data = array(
               'user_status' => 'active'


         );*/
           $query=$this->db->select('user_ID');
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $data['user_ID'] = $rajan; 

      if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $query->row_array();
            $user_ID= $row['user_ID'];
        }





                for($i=1; $i<=$data;$i++)
                    {

                    $userdata=array('user_status'=>'active'


                     );

                    $this->db->update('users',$userdata);

                    }





       //redirect('admin/index');


 }
```

Answer (score 3):

$this->db->where('id',$user_id);
$this->db->update('users',$userdata);

specify where clause

Comment: there's an error with the code you gave, I tried approving the id 78 it turned out that id 73 was approved instead of 78. I then did it once more therefore it only determines and then approves the lowest id. I placed the code inside for loop.